# Is there a package that can filter the `raw_feature_bc_matrix` of 10X's `cellranger multi` pipeline output?

Tags: single-cell

There is no `filtered_feature_bc_matrix` in 10X Genomics' `cellranger multi` pipeline output when multiplexing analysis was performed.
There are indeed `sample_filtered_feature_bc_matrix` for each sample after demultiplexing. But there are still some No tag-assigned cells that are not included in any sample, and I have to filter those cells before analysis.
Is there a package that can filter the `raw_feature_bc_matrix` of `cellranger multi` pipeline output?
Is this package `scCB2`(https://github.com/zijianni/scCB2) suitable for this purpose?

I tried scCB2 with the following parameters, I am not sure whether these parameters will produce similar output with cellranger’s filter method.

```
library(scCB2)
library(SummarizedExperiment)

for (i in data_file) {
    print(i)
    tmp =  QuickCB2(dir = i, FDR_threshold = 0.01, lower = 100, Ncores = 12)
    DropletUtils::write10xCounts(paste0("./data/filtered/", basename(i)), tmp, version = "3")
}
```

I got 83836 cells after filtering, but the `tag_calls_per_cell.csv` file of the `multiplexing_analysis` only contains 19427 cells.
It seems I have to use a more stringent filter.

Is there a python package that can do a similar thing?
Thanks

Comment: I can work around this by only selecting cells in the `assignment_confidence_table.csv`. (https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/output/cellplex?src=social&lss=facebook&cnm=soc-fb-ra_g-program&cid=7011P000000y06x/#:~:text=Description-,assignment_confidence_table.csv,-A%20table%20that)